# NETGEAR PCMCIA wireless Card Drivers?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, netgear

I Am thinking about purchasing a NETGEAR WPN511 RangeMax PCMCIA Wireless card; but I was wondering -- is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04? Will I need to download drivers; or are drivers for it already in 12.04?

I just want find out so that I don't get something I can't use.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered your question in another forum, but in the meantime I solved my problem with my wpn511 pcmcia card in 12.04!
Now I can say it runs without any problems. At first the internet speed was very slow and unstable, but then I googled my way out of it. It was a pain in the a**, but I eventually did it and it is quite simple:

Ubuntu 12.04 already comes with the atheros chipset driver you need (ath5k) for the wpn511 pcmcia card, but it seems to be badly configured. So what you have to do is:

1. In Terminal: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf`
2. Add line or write it as the first line as the file was empty, like in my case: options ath5k nohwcrypt=1
3. Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>, then enter)
4. Enjoy

Hope this helps!

Comment: "I already answered your question in another forum," -- I Don't Remember posting the question in another forum... 

Regardless, I already Purchased it and it seems to work very well. I haven't had any problems with it so far; But If any problems arise, I will try that out. ^-^